# Angular kendo combo box cannot hide when no data

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-combobox

I'm working with angular and kendo, I use kendo combobox to display some value as [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjkt3j?file=app/app.component.ts).

I want to hide the popup when no data match, but I cannot do that.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `[combobox.toggle()][1]` in filter function when `data.length` is zero and `combobox.isOpen` is false

**Template**

```
 <div class="example-wrapper">
          <kendo-combobox
            #combo
              [data]="data"
              [textField]="'text'"
              [valueField]="'value'"
              [filterable]="true"
              (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)"
              [placeholder]="'T-shirt size'"
          >
          <ng-template kendoComboBoxNoDataTemplate>
            No data found!
          </ng-template>
          </kendo-combobox>
      </div>
```

**component**

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('combo') combo:ComboBoxComponent

    public source: Array<{ text: string, value: number }> = [
        { text: 'Small', value: 1 },
        { text: 'Medium', value: 2 },
        { text: 'Large', value: 3 }
    ];

    public data: Array<{ text: string, value: number }>;

    constructor() {
        this.data = this.source.slice();
    }

    handleFilter(value) {
        this.data = this.source.filter((s) => s.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);

      if(this.data.length == 0 && this.combo.isOpen){
    this.combo.toggle()
  }
    }
}
```

[this is full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjkt3j-3pb57s?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Wow it working, that great, @hanan Thank you so much for your help.